# Save multiple upload with clientOriginalName

Tags: laravel

hy everyone,, i want to upload multiple file with OriginalClientName, save into database with column called **"document"** but when data saved into database the file when uploading is not same the name,, i am upload file with name "cv bimo.docx", but in database, the name like this:

```
C:\Users\bimo_an\AppData\Local\Temp\phpAAF.tmp
```

[image]

i already using method **getClientOriginalName()**,,

this is my Function controller code :

```
..............................
 $uploadFile = $request->file('document');
        foreach($uploadFile as $file){
          $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $folder[] = $file->storeAs('uploads', $filename);
        }
        $data = [
                        'mto_number'=>$request->txtDocNumber,
                        'item_code'=>$request->txtItemCode[$key],
                        'required_qty'=>$request->txtRequiredQty[$key],
                        'spare_qty'=>$request->txtSpareQty[$key],
                        // 'file' => $path[$key]
                        'category' => $request->category[$key],
                        'document' => $file
        ];
        ModelMTOItem::insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing file Path instead of clientOriginalName

```
$uploadFile = $request->file('document');
    foreach($uploadFile as $file) {

        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $data = [
            'mto_number'=>$request->txtDocNumber,
            'item_code'=>$request->txtItemCode[$key],
            'required_qty'=>$request->txtRequiredQty[$key],
            'spare_qty'=>$request->txtSpareQty[$key],
            // 'file' => $path[$key]
            'category' => $request->category[$key],
            'document' => $filename
        ];

        ModelMTOItem::insert($data);

        $folder[] = $file->storeAs('uploads', $filename);
    }
```